# wc_get_products is not returning related product id's

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I try to use `wc_get_products` in `functions.php` in WordPress. However, I have 2 problems. I only can see the data when using `var_dump` and the response is missing `related_ids` (relatable product id's).

The original WooCommerce api call `/wp-json/wc/v3/products` does return the related_ids (when calling from e.g. postman). BUT the `wc_get_products()`in PHP does not.

#### Code in functions.php

```php
$productArgs = array(
     'numberposts' => -1,
     'post_status' => 'published',
     'include' => array(108903),
    );
$products = wc_get_products( $productArgs );

var_dump($products);
return $products;
```

I use the follow documentation: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query, but I don't see any information about related product id's.

Answer (score 0):

By default, only the API returns the `related_ids`. To get the related ids for a product you may need to use the function `wc_get_related_products`.

```
$productArgs = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'published',
    'include' => array(108903),
);
$products = wc_get_products($productArgs);
$related_ids = array_map('absint', array_values(wc_get_related_products(108903)));
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! I think we are almost there. I need to get the related product id's for multiple product id's. Can I do something like this: $related_ids = array_map('absint', array_values(wc_get_related_products(array(108903,108842))));
Or do I need to loop through all my product id's and then call `wc_get_related_products`?

Comment: Also, when I do `return $products;`, the array is empty, but when I `var_dump` they show me the data. Probably because the data is `protected`, how can I still return the data?

Comment: Hey, I think I fixed it. I just looped through the array and called `wc_get_related_products`. For the other problem, I loop through the products and call `$product->get_data()` and add the actual product into a new array :)